# A couple basic bootstrap questions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a practice assignment in bootstrap just to show the automatic resizing as the window is changed, I have never really worked with bootstrap before, but I managed to get it setup with fairly minimal effort. however my two columns are not properly leveling at near the bottom of the page.

here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat appplication</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class ="container" min-height: 80%>
<div class="row"  >
    <div class = "col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid black"> <center> You are known as Emerald Dragon in Nirvana room</center> </div>
</div>

<div class ="row">
    <div class = "col-md-8" style="border: 1px solid black"> <font color="blue" font size="1">:INFO James has joined Nirvana room </font> 
    <font size ="1">

    <p>James: Hi, Dragon </p>
    <p> Emerald Dragon: What's up </p>
    </font> </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid black"> <font size ="4"> <center> List of available rooms </center> 

    <font size ="1">
    <p>Lobby</p>
    <p>Conference room</p>
    <p>Lab</p>
    <p>Coffe house</p>
    <p> Nirvans</p>
    </font>

    </div>

   </div>
</div>  

</html>
```

This is what my code is producing
https://gyazo.com/a550bac980fc12ad703fcab1cf2af94e

also if I resize the screen it does not automatically resize the tables it just joins them vertically, I think this is because I haven't yet declared the bootstrap variants for the different screen sizes.

https://gyazo.com/f620e42da5299f3ca8bb186bd2c05407

Comment: OK just a note I successfully managed to get the resizing function to work. I was correct in having to assign the different parameters for the different screen sizes.

Comment: By the way, on line 8, you should put min-height: 80% inside the style attribute like style="min-height: 80%;"

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the bootstrap. It's your html/css code. You'll have to set a specific height for the row div then set the height of the two columns to 100% so that their height will fill up the whole height of the row div.

Here's what I did to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat appplication</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class ="container" min-height: 80%>
<div class="row"  >
    <div class = "col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid black"> <center> You are known as Emerald Dragon in Nirvana room</center> </div>
</div>

<div class ="row" style="height: 150px">
    <div class = "col-md-8" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100%"> <font color="blue" font size="1">:INFO James has joined Nirvana room </font> 
    <font size ="1">

    <p>James: Hi, Dragon </p>
    <p> Emerald Dragon: What's up </p>
    </font> </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100%"> <font size ="4"> <center> List of available rooms </center> 

    <font size ="1">
    <p>Lobby</p>
    <p>Conference room</p>
    <p>Lab</p>
    <p>Coffe house</p>
    <p> Nirvans</p>
    </font>

    </div>

   </div>
</div>  

</html>
```

**EDIT**

For the tables then you'll have to use `<table>` and not `<div>`. You separated the divs that's why it aligns vertically if you resize the screen.